# django-file upload request refresh

Tags: python, django, apache, file-upload

Everything is ok when I am testing with django test server (manage.py runserver) but when i'm using it with apache2, after POSTing a form containing pdf file, The request with POST data get closed and a second request with no POST data is sent.

Chrome network screenshot:

[image]

Why this is this happening and what must I do to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

finally, I used [nginx](https://nginx.org/) instead of [apache2](https://httpd.apache.org) and everything got OK.